# Wookmark not changing layout

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, wookmark

In my rails 3.2 project, I'm currently using the gem version of [wookmark](https://github.com/roadt/jquery-wookmark-rails) and it seems to be working since I can see the asset being loaded in the development logs.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.wookmark
//= require_tree .
```

like so:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.wookmark.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-01-16 07:59:12 +0000
```

Then in my HTML, I've laid out the elements which I wish wookmark to layout as such:

```
<div id="post-container">
  <% Post.all.each do |individual_post| %>
      <%= render 'shared/posts/individual_post', locals: { individual_post: individual_post } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

which calls the following partial:

```
<div class="well post">
  <p>Title: <%= link_to locals[:individual_post].title, locals[:individual_post].url, target: '_blank' %></p>
  <p>Content: <%= raw(locals[:individual_post].content) %></p>
</div>
```

I then added the javascript to handle the initializing in the `<head>` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".post").wookmark({
            offset: 5,
            autoResize: true
        });
    });
  </script>
```

I don't see any errors in the chrome console but yet the layout is not tiled. Have I missed anything here?

Extra details: jquery-rails(3.0.4), bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

It seems the plugin requires both css and javascript files in order for this technique to work. Since the gem contains only the javascript files required, I have gone ahead and directly used the original plugin by downloading the css and javascript files instead.

Hope this helps anyone that has the same issue!